# Magento Connect Manager

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, magento-connect

We are running Magento ver. 1.7.0.2.  On the admin page, there is no option under system for Magento Connect.  We have an account with Magento Connect.  Is there something that needs to be done to associate that account with the Magento Admin page?

Comment: Did it suddenly disappear?

Comment: I am not sure.  I was not aware of it before this so I don't remember if it was there before or not.

Comment: Did someone turned it of in the admin user rules?

Comment: How/where would I find that out?

Answer (score 0):

Double check under `System -> Config -> Advanced -> Advanced` that Mage_Connect is listed and enabled.

Another possibility, make sure you have the `downloader` folder in your Magento root.  I was missing this folder once, and just grabbed it from the Magento release at: https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/magento/

Comment: Mage_connect is listed and enabled.  I am not familiar with coding so I do not know where to look to see if the downloader file is in the Magento root.

Comment: The Magento root folder contains other folders like `app`,`errors`,`includes`,`js`,`lib`,`media`, etc.  `downloader` should be in there as well.